# Angularjs UI-Grid column ordering

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angularjs ui-grid and it's working well on desktop as well as on mobile also but when I try to move ui-grid columns on mobile or touchable devices then they are not being moved.
Here is my [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/V3myICAYNti9MxhEbV0A?p=preview):

Any help would be appreciated.
Below is code attached also.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-move-columns class="grid"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And js file code is:-

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.moveColumns']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        columnDefs: [{
            name: 'firstName',
            field: 'first-name'
        }, {
            name: '1stFriend',
            field: 'friends[0]'
        }, {
            name: 'city',
            field: 'address.city'
        }, {
            name: 'getZip',
            field: 'getZip()',
            enableCellEdit: false
        }],
        data: [{
            "first-name": "Cox",
            "friends": ["friend0"],
            "address": {
                street: "301 Dove Ave",
                city: "Laurel",
                zip: "39565"
            },
            "getZip": function() {
                return this.address.zip;
            }
        }]
    };

}]);
```

Comment: you can try using bootstrap's responsive table http://plnkr.co/edit/GYTJIDPyoCAgEajbdfOu?p=preview

Comment: @NitsanBaleli, on your given plnkr, columns are not being dragged/movable on touchable devices.

Comment: It seems like there was a problem on iOS devices. And some of them is believed to be fixed. But it is quite old issue in github. You may look there: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/1551